# Choose from two subjects for mail based on entry in cell

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I need to make this condition for mail subject:
If the time in cell S5 != 00:00 then put the text which is in cell S5.
Else put the text which is in cell T5.

```vb
Sub esendtable()

Dim outlook As Object
Dim newEmail As Object
Dim xInspect As Object
Dim pageEditor As Object

Set outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set newEmail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
Set xInspect = newEmail.GetInspector
Set pageEditor = xInspect.WordEditor

With newEmail
    .To = Sheet1.Range("S2").Text
    .CC = Sheet1.Range("S3").Text
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = Sheet1.Range("S5").Text
    .Body = "Dear All," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbTab & Sheet1.Range("S6").Text
    .Recipients.ResolveAll
    .display
        
    Sheet1.Range("B2:L12").Copy
      
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.Body)
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.End = pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
    .display
    
    Set pageEditor = Nothing
    Set xInspect = Nothing
End With

Set newEmail = Nothing
Set outlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `if-else` condition. If `S5 = 00:00` then the subject will be value of `T5` cell else it will be value of `S5` cell.

**Condition:**

```
If subject = "00:00" Then

subject = Sheet1.Range("T5").Text

Else

subject = Sheet1.Range("S5").Text

End If
```

**Complete code:**

```
Sub esendtable()

Dim outlook As Object

Dim newEmail As Object

Dim xInspect As Object

Dim pageEditor As Object

Set outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set newEmail = outlook.CreateItem(0)

Set xInspect = newEmail.GetInspector

Set pageEditor = xInspect.WordEditor

Dim subject As String

subject = Sheet1.Range("S5").Value

If subject = "00:00" Then

subject = Sheet1.Range("T5").Text

Else

subject = Sheet1.Range("S5").Text

End If

With newEmail

    .To = Sheet1.Range("S2").Text
    .CC = Sheet1.Range("S3").Text
    .BCC = ""
    .subject = subject
    .Body = "Dear All," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbTab & Sheet1.Range("S6").Text
    .Recipients.ResolveAll
    .display
        
    Sheet1.Range("B2:L12").Copy
      
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.Body)
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.End = pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
    .display
    
    Set pageEditor = Nothing
    Set xInspect = Nothing
End With

Set newEmail = Nothing

Set outlook = Nothing

End Sub
```